# I want to migrate my HDD to SSD but also want to completly wipe my C

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd

So my end goal is to migrate my OS from my HDD to my SSD, and since i dont have any CD of my windows 7 (wasn't delivered with my pc, and I didn't make any backup).

I have 1 HDD 2TB in my computer and it is (upon delivery) devided into 2 pieces, 922GB for C(windows) and 922GB for D (data).

Question is..:
1. If i wipe my whole disk will i lose everything or just my C?
2. If i factory reset my whole system, will I lose my C or also my D?
--> So what i want to achieve is to delete everything, from my C but to retain everything on D and obviously my OS on my C. 
--> what should I do?

Kind regards.

Comment: Really? Just get a Windows CD for all the trouble it's worth. Also, wiping just the C is possible, but you need a disc of some sort... Probably partitions.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your title says one thing and the body another, making this confusing and difficult to follow. There are too many questions being asked, with such vague detail, there is no way for us to answer without simply giving opinions. Please take a minute to ***[edit]*** your question to include details and only ask a single main question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Find your windows 7 installation key. (If this is a legit OEM installation of Windows, it should be printed on a sticker attached to your PC, or possibly attached to some documentation you got with the PC.)

2) Download a Windows 7 disc from Microsoft's website and burn to a DVD.

3) Have both drives plugged in. When you are installing, you can selecft your new drive to install to. Once installed, go back after and format the old C drive partition. You will not be touching the D drive.

Answer (score 0):

> If I wipe my whole disk will I lose everything or just my C?

Yes;  You will lose everything on the disk if you delete the existing partitions of the disk you format.

> If I factory reset my whole system, will I lose my C or also my D?

This depends on the factory image itself.  You should backup any data you are worried about.

> So what I want to achieve is to delete everything, from my C but to
>   retain everything on D and obviously my OS on my C.  How can I achieve
>   this?

You backup all your user data to an external storage device.  You [download](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) the appropriate version of Windows 7 based on the [version you currently have installed](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/).

The linked content is a bunch of direct downloads and a 35 second video so you can determine what version of Windows you have installed.